# Can't see dbContext class from core class library in .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

In my solution I have a .NET Core project and a class library. The class library is a layer for communicating with a database. I'm getting the error "OrderDataContext is inaccessible due to its protection level", even if I add a reference.

OrderDataAcces is my class library where I have OrderDataContext class, and OrderWebApi is my .net core class, where I defined connectionString in startup.cs:

[image]

[image: Added reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to OrderDataAccess Library is not enough to solve your problem.

Your OrderDataContext class is probably not marked as public.

You probably have "class OrderDataContext" instead of "public class OrderDataContext".